# divide the money value to zero?

Tags: c#, sql-server, accounting

i have a problem to divide the money value to "0".
i build accounting software, with a shrinking asset.

example, i have a value 1000000. 
i would divide it into 3.

1000000 / 3 =  333333,33333333333333333333333

the question is, i would to do this:

> step 1 :1000000 - 333333,33333333333333333333333 =
>   666666,66666666666666666666667
>
> step 2 :666666,66666666666666666666667 - 
>   333333,33333333333333333333333 =  333333,33333333333333333333334
>
> step 3 :333333,33333333333333333333334 -
>   333333,33333333333333333333333 =
>   **0,00000000000000000000001**

**example code**

```
decimal value = 100;
int divider = 3;
decimal x = value / divider;

for (int i = 0; i < divider; i++)
{
    value = value - x;
}
```

the result, value = 0,000000000000000000000000001 .

yeah, that is a problem.
that a money value, i would divide to zero.

I've tried using math method like a "math.floor" at each step (on loop).
the result value is -2.
i know i can using "math.floor" method for the final result. but i don't, because i want to do step to step (on loop.)
what should i do?

thanks

Comment: you should post your code.

Comment: No sure which currency you work in but I'll use British pounds as an example. If I had £100 and wanted to divide it 3 ways, I am forced to have 1 penny left over or give someone that extra penny. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidG I want to do Depreciation of Assets in accounting

Comment: Which method are you using? Are you doing reducing balance or straight line?

Comment: @DavidG i use straight line method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider multiplying your 1/3 by 1, 2, or 3 instead of subtracting the previous number. Something like this should work:

```
var originalAmount = 1000000d;
var thirdOfOriginal = originalAmount / 3;

Console.WriteLine("Original number ... {0}", originalAmount);
Console.WriteLine("Original - 1/3 .... {0}", (originalAmount - (thirdOfOriginal * 1)));
Console.WriteLine("Original - 2/3 .... {0}", (originalAmount - (thirdOfOriginal * 2)));
Console.WriteLine("Original - 3/3 .... {0}", (originalAmount - (thirdOfOriginal * 3)));

// Output
// Original number ... 1000000
// Original - 1/3 .... 666666.666666667
// Original - 2/3 .... 333333.333333333
// Original - 3/3 .... 0
```

This could be written more generically as:

```
private static List<decimal> GetAmounts(decimal originalNumber, int numberOfDivisions)
{
    var amounts = new List<decimal>();

    if (numberOfDivisions > 0)
    {
        var fraction = originalNumber / numberOfDivisions;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDivisions; i++)
        {
            amounts.Add(originalNumber - (fraction * i));
        }
    }

    return amounts;
}
```